# How can I say that someone's a perfect example of being able to perform a certain skill?

Tags: word-choice

For example, Mao Asada is representative of triple axel.

Which is to say that she's a perfect example of someone who can perform a triple axel. Does it make sense to use: representative of (skill), being the epitome of (skill)? Byword perhaps? I know byword is used with a quality, for example "In Hollywood's golden era,"Betty" was a byword for glamour." how can I express the same talking about a skill?

Comment: She sets the standard ... She's the epitome of perfection with ...

Comment: I think you're looking for "exemplification", although I'm not sure you should go there.

Comment: Is it the person who is perfect, of their execution of the triple axel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 3 options are [exemplar](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/exemplar), [paradigm](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/paradigm), and [paragon](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/paragon):

> **exemplar**: A typical or good example of something: *It is an exemplar of a house of the period*
>
> **paradigm**: A very clear or typical example used as a model: *His ruthless accumulation of wealth stands as a paradigm of greed in the business world.*
>
> **paragon**: A person or thing that is perfect or has a large amount of a particularly good characteristic: *A paragon of virtue*

I don't think *paradigm* is typically used to reference a *person*, so you might be better off using one of the other two:

> Mao Asada is an exemplar of the triple axle.

*or*

> Mao Asada is a paragon of the triple axle.